# What is the difference in these deletes

Tags: mysql

These deletes are deleting the repetition from the table

Works perfectly:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT t.id 
                 FROM
                     (SELECT MAX(ID) AS id FROM mytable 
                      GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) t);
```

The workbench accept and run it but never finish it:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(t.ID) AS id 
                 FROM 
                     (SELECT * FROM mytable) AS t
                 GROUP BY t.col1, t.col2, t.col3);
```

After 30 sec I get: "Lost connection to MySQL server during query 30.000 sec"

In the list of processes the query is in 'Sending data' state.

Why the second one doesn't work, what is the difference?

I am using mysql.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] ?

Comment: The first one looks like it has a redundant SELECT, you use SELECT on a result that only contains one value (or null)

Comment: And so does the second. Why not just `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS id FROM mytable GROUP BY t.col1, t.col2, t.col3);`?

Comment: @user207421 Because it is mysql. If I do so I will get: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'mytable' for update in FROM clause. You have to make a query.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it can contains multiple values.